# What are the recipes in Education Edition?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

Education Edition gives a concept of chemistry, and gives out new recipes. What are these recipes and how can I make them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All recipes are found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compound), but will be restated here.

### Compounds

| Compounds | Recipe |
| --- | --- |
| **Aluminium Oxide** | Al<sup>2</sup>O<sup>3</sup> |
| **Ammonia** | NH<sup>3</sup> |
| **Barium Sulfate** | BaSO<sup>4</sup> |
| **Benzene** | C<sup>6</sup>H<sup>6</sup> |
| **Borium Trioxide** | B<sup>2</sup>O<sup>3</sup> |
| **Calcium Bromide** | CaBr<sup>2</sup> |
| **Crude Oil** | C<sup>9</sup>H<sup>20</sup> |
| **Glue (Cyanoacrylate)** | C<sup>5</sup>H<sup>5</sup>NO<sup>2</sup> |
| **Hydrogen Peroxide** | H<sup>2</sup>O<sup>2</sup> |
| **Iron Sulfide** | FeS |
| **Latex** | C<sup>5</sup>H<sup>8</sup> |
| **Lithium Hydride** | LiH |
| **Luminol** | C<sup>8</sup>H<sup>7</sup>N<sup>3</sup>O<sup>2</sup> |
| **Lye** | NaOH |
| **Magnesium Nitrate** | MgN<sup>2</sup>O<sup>6</sup> |
| **Magnesium Oxide** | MgO |
| **Polyethylene** | C<sup>10</sup>H<sup>20</sup> |
| **Potassium Iodide** | KI |
| **Soap** | C<sup>18</sup>H<sup>35</sup>NaO<sup>2</sup> |
| **Sodium Acetate** | C<sup>2</sup>H<sup>3</sup>NaO<sup>2</sup> |
| **Sodium Fluoride** | NaF |
| **Sodium Hydride** | NaH |
| **Sodium Hypochlorite** | NaClO |
| **Sodium Oxide** | Na<sup>2</sup>O |
| **Sulfate** | SO<sup>4</sup> |

| Chlorides | Recipe |
| --- | --- |
| **Calcium Chloride** | CaCl<sup>2</sup> |
| **Cerium Chloride** | CeCl<sup>3</sup> |
| **Mercuric Chloride** | HgCl<sup>2</sup> |
| **Potassium Chloride** | KCl |
| **Salt (Sodium Chloride)** | NaCl |
| **Tungsten Chloride** | WCl<sup>6</sup> |

| Natural compounds | Chemical formula |
| --- | --- |
| **Charcoal** | C<sup>7</sup>H<sup>4</sup>O |
| **Ink Sac** | FeSO<sup>4</sup> |
| **Sugar** | C<sup>6</sup>H<sup>12</sup>O<sup>6</sup> |
| **Water** | H<sup>2</sup>O |

### Craftable Items

| Crafting ingredient | Illustrated recipe | Components |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [**Balloon**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Balloon) | [image: Balloon Recipe] | 1 Dye (of your choice), 6 Latex, 1 Lead, 1 Helium |
| [**Glow Stick**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glow_Stick) | [image: Glow Stick Recipe] | 1 Dye (of your choice), 1 Hydrogen Peroxide, 1 Luminol, 1 Polyethylene |
| [**Hardened Glass**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hardened_Glass) | [image: Hardened Glass Recipe] | 3 Aluminium Oxide, 3 Boron Trioxide, 3 Glass |